# Concatenate a dynamic Number of columns Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to concatenate x number of columns per project sometimes it's 3 columns others 7 or 5, it just depends

I am trying to this with an array of range column numbers ex  [2,5,3]

columns 2,5 3 in that order with a delimiter here `|`

I have searched but found only static concatenating functions

I have a VBA Macro that works as I need in Excel so I am trying to write it in Google Script

The function runs without erroring but nothing is posted back
From Logger.log() I am kinda close to the proper structure

I get `undefined|b|e|c`

I want to post back to the last column + 1

I am not sure this is the best way to do this but it what I have
Any help is appreciated, Thanks

```
colA    ColB   ColC    ColD    ColE    ColF    ColG    ColH
  a      b      cc      d        e      f        g      b|e|c
  a2     b2             d2       e2     f2       g2     e2|c2

  ect.
```

Here is what I have:

```
function TemplateA_n() {

  Template_A("A", [2, 4, 6])

}


function Template_A(SshtName, sArr){
  var sSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SshtName);
  var sR = sSheet.getDataRange();
  var sV = sR.getValues();
  var sLC = sSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sLR = sSheet.getLastRow();

  var a = []
  //Rows
  for (var row = 2; row < sLR; row++){
     a[row] =[]

    //Columns
    for (var col = 0; col < sArr.length ; col++){

      if(sV[row][sArr[col]] !== "") {
        if(sV[row][sArr[0]] == "") {
          a[row][0] = a[row][0] + sV[row][sArr[col]];
          Logger.log(a[row][0])
        }
         else {
               a[row][0] = a[row][0] + "|" + sV[row][sArr[col]];   
               Logger.log(a[row][0])
        }
      }
   }
 }

  sSheet.getRange(1,sLC + 1,sLR,1);
}
```

Here is the Macro

```
Sub ConCatA()
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, i As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select column(s)", Type:=8)
'Set rng = Range("B1,A1,C1")
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ReDim a(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    a(1, 1) = "Concat"

    For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
        For Each r In rng
            If .Cells(i, r.Column) <> "" Then
               a(i, 1) = a(i, 1) & IIf(a(i, 1) = "", "", "|") & .Cells(i, r.Column).value
            End If
        Next r
    Next i

    With .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
         .value = a
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1: Undefined value in output**

The reason you get the following ouput: `undefined|b|e|c` is because the variable `a[row][0]` is undefined before you assign it any value. So when program runs the following line of code for the first time in the loop it concats the value of `sV[row][sArr[col]]`to undefined.

```
a[row][0] = a[row][0] + sV[row][sArr[col]]
```

All you need to do is assign an empty value to begin with, like so

```
for (var row = 2; row < sLR; row++){
     a[row] =[]
     a[row][0] = ""
     ... your code here 
  }
```

Also, since the assignment of values only start from index 2 in the loop, we need to assign index 0 and 1.

```
a[0] = [""]
a[1] = [""]
```

This will enable us to input blank values in the sheet when we use setvalues function with this array.
**Part 2: Append values to sheet (lastColumn + 1)**
You define the range to append your data and then set its values, as follows:

```
var appRange = Sheet.getRange(2,sLC+1,a.length,1)
appRange.setValues(a)
```

Your final code would look like this:

```
    function Template_A(SshtName, sArr){
  var sSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SshtName);
  var sR = sSheet.getDataRange();
  var sV = sR.getValues();
  var sLC = sSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sLR = sSheet.getLastRow();

  var a = []
  //Rows
  a[0]= [""]     // Since you are start from index 1, you need to assign a value to index 0
  for (var row = 1; row < sLR; row++){   //If you intended to start from 2nd row
                                         // var row = 1 and not 2
     a[row] = []
     a[row][0] = ""                 //Empty value for each row 
    //Columns
    for (var col = 0; col < sArr.length ; col++){

      if(sV[row][sArr[col]-1] !== "") {
        if(a[row][0] == "") {     //Check to see if the array is empty
                                  // If yes donot add "|"
          a[row][0] = a[row][0] + sV[row][sArr[col]-1];
          Logger.log(a[row][0])
        }
         else {
               a[row][0] = a[row][0] + "|" + sV[row][sArr[col]-1];   
               Logger.log(a[row][0])
        }
      }
   }
 }
  Logger.log(a)
  var appRange = sSheet.getRange(1,sLC+1,a.length,1)
  appRange.setValues(a)
}
```

**Final Note:** If you intend to skip the first row in your sheet your loop should start with counter 1. Since array index starts from 0 but row numbering in sheet start from 1.

Comment: Jack, thanks for the response. I get this error `Cannot convert Array to Object[][]` for this `appRange.setValues(a)`. The explanation was fantastic!

Comment: Should be fixed now, please note the use of `sArr[col]-1` in array index. Again to fix for change for index change from sheet numbering to array numbering.

Comment: Jack, this great, thanks for the code and the annotation very helpful to understanding